# Next.js App Router with i18next is not working

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, next.js14, app-route

Next.js App Router with i18next translation is not working properly for the client component. It always shows text in the default language.

I have used TranslationsProvider on RootLayout Like This.

```
export default async function RootLayout({
    children,
    params: { locale }
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
    params:{
        locale: string
    }
}>) {

    const {resources} = await initTranslations(locale, i18nNamespaces);

    return (
        <html lang={locale}>
            <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
                <SessionProvider>
                    <TranslationsProvider namespaces={i18nNamespaces} locale={locale} resources={resources}>
                        {children}
                    </TranslationsProvider>
                </SessionProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

My Client Component Code

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

export default function Settings() {

    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <form>
            <section>
                <div className="grid gap-10 grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-12">
                    <div className="sm:col-span-5">
                        <h2 className="mb-5 font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                            {t("settings")}
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            {t("settings_description_1")}
                        </p>
                        <p className="mt-2.5">
                            {t("settings_description_2")}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="sm:col-span-7 p-6 rounded-sm border border-stroke bg-white shadow-default dark:border-strokedark">
                        <h3 className="mb-5 font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                            {t("settings_input_heading")}
                        </h3>

                        <input type="text" className="w-full border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 font-normal text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary" />

                        <p className="mt-2.5">
                            {t("settings_input_description")}
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

When I use const { t } = useTranslation(); in my nested Client Component then Translations is not working. It always shows text in the default language. But for the nested Server Component, it is working fine.